# Data-remote modal-body loading bar for bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my Code for edit vehicle modal call

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($vhcl);$i++){
echo "<a data-toggle='modal' href=' ' data-remote='using/vehicles/vehicle-form.php?id=".$vhcl[$i]['mvid']."&m=e' data-target='#vehicle-modal'><i class='icon-pencil color-orange'></i></a>";
} ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="vehicle-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Now when I first time click on this link it takes few seconds and modal appears with 1st vehicle edit data,

But now when I click on 2nd vehicle modal appears instantly with same data, and its refreshed after 2 3 seconds( it may also take more time in slow connections ).

So question is can we have any modal-body load completed check ?

Until the modal body is loaded with new refreshed data, loading image should be there in modal body and then the actual data.

Comment: use $.ajax available in jQuery (use loading image in  beforeSend function)

Comment: But how to integrate this with data-remote? I have not used ajax call for this modals. Can you please give hint?

Comment: try [https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

Try to call modal using javascript instead of attributes. Before modal start to download remote path content you can delete the modal content.

[This is example in **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5mme/6/)

**Html:**

```
<a href='#' class="open-modal" data-remote='http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/22/show/'><i class='icon-pencil color-orange'></i></a>
<br/>
<a href='#' class="open-modal" data-remote='http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/40/show/'><i class='icon-pencil color-orange'></i></a>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){    
    $("a.open-modal").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var modal=$("#modal");
        modal.empty();
        modal.append("<div class='modal fade modal-dialog' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'></div>");
        $('.modal-dialog').modal({
            remote:$(e.currentTarget).attr("data-remote")
        });
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

You also can place some image or text like "Loading..." while loading.

[This is example in **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5mme/11/)

**Html:**

```
<span id="onLoad" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;z-index:1000000;" hidden>Loading...</span>
<a href='#' class="open-modal" data-remote='http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/22/show/'><i class='icon-pencil color-orange'></i></a>
<br/>
<a href='#' class="open-modal" data-remote='http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/40/show/'><i class='icon-pencil color-orange'></i></a>
<div class='modal fade' id='modal-dialog' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){      
    $("a.open-modal").click(function(e){
        $('#onLoad').show();        
        e.preventDefault();
        var modal=$("#modal-dialog");
        modal.empty();        
        modal.modal({
        }).load($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-remote"), function (e) {
            $('#onLoad').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why does your solution only work in jsfiddle? For example, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/m5mme/11/show/ the dialog doesn't show up anymore?

Comment: @Jonathan, it doesn't appear because your link has different domain than the remote data has. `jsfiddle.net` and `jsfiddle.jshell.net`. For example check this one: [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m5mme/11/show/) it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easier solution based on the @Nicolai's solution
I was experiencing issues with the solutions above, that's I'm also posting my solution, so someone can get it correctly in future :)

HTML:

```
<a class="open-custom-modal" data-remote="/url/1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#custom_modal">URL 1</a>
<br />
<a class="open-custom-modal" data-remote="/url/2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#custom_modal">URL 1</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="custom_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="custom_modal_label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.open-custom-modal").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#custom_modal').modal({
         }).find('.modal-body').load($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-remote"), function(e) {
            //loading completes here
         });
    });
});
```